# Ghost Singapore Safe app will not delete

Tags: applications

I purchased a Samsung phone while in Singapore, it has the usual pre installed apps and the covid 19 SGsecure app. The app is greyed out and has no delete option when clicked on it says "app not installed". I ve just re-flashed the firmware using ODEN with what i thought was Australian firmware but the SGsecure app icon is still there,  did i not flash it correctly ?is it possible to delete?